# Calling SKScene method from GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

While in the GameViewController, I want to access methods from one of my SKScenes. Its class is called `PlayScene`.

I have been trying to work it out, but haven't managed it. I'm trying things like `let gameScene = self.something.something as! PlayScene`

I also tried using `let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` but then when I tried to call the method it said something like "unresolved identifier." I use this when I present this scene, so I thought it would work.

Am I close? How can I access my SKScene class from GameViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to cast the `SKScene` as a `PlayScene`.

```
let playScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as? PlayScene
```

Now the compiler knows that your `SkScene` is also a `PlayScene`, and you can call `PlayScene` methods on it.

Comment: How does this answer change if I need a specific instance of PlayScene?

Comment: I assume you want the scene that your `SKView` is presenting? You should have a reference to it in the `GameViewController`. Just store it as a property.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. So for this case I'd use `self` somehow, right?

Comment: You can use the `self` keyword to refer to properties on a class, yes. However, it can be omitted in most cases.